# Hbase master failing to start exception Java.Lang.NoSuchMethodException

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hdfs

I'm following Lars George Hbase definitive guide. I'm in the process of setting up a pseudo distributed cluster on my Mountain Lion Macbook pro.I downloaded Hadoop archive 0.20.205.0, untarred and made a few minor changes

```
dfs.replication=1
```

and others. When I made the changes in hbase-site.xml to specify localhost hdfs namenode as in

```
hbase.rootdir=hdfs://localhost:9000/hbase
```

and a few other properties like

```
zookeeperquorum, zookeeperdataDir, isDistributed=true
```

and so forth.

However, on running

```
bin/start-hbase.sh
```

I was unable to access webui at 60010. On running, jps, I noticed the master of hbase was dying fast. So I accessed master log and found this exception thrown

```
2629 2013-06-23 14:22:43,694 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.FSUtils: Unable to create version file at hdfs://localhost:9000/hbase, retrying: java.io.IOException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.Client     Protocol.create(java.lang.String, org.apache.hadoop.fs.permission.FsPermission, java.lang.String, boolean, boolean, short, long)
2630     at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1607)
2631     at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:557)
2632     at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1388)
2633     at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1384)
2634     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
2635     at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
2636     at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1059)
2637     at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1382)
```

I don't want to repeat what everyone postfixes when they post questions like these, I'm a newbie please help :) But I really am a newbie did what I had to do, couldnt find the answer, any pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Noticed several strange things, there was no hadoop-core-*.jar within the hadoop distro I'd downloaded, whereas my hbase distro had one {0.94.7} I'm sure it is some sort of versioning problem, but I need more clarity as to what's going on???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use HBase in pseudo(or fully) distributed mode it has got some dependencies on hadoop libraries(like RPC version might get changed because of a change in protocol). That's why you need proper Hadoop jars in your Hase/lib folder.

Because of these dependencies each version of HBase comes bundled with an instance of the Hadoop jars under its lib directory. It might be that the bundled Hadoop was made from some branch, at the time of your HBase's release, which is different from the one you are using at present. `For example,` you are using hbase-0.94.7 which is quite latest as compared to hadoop-0.20.205. That is why, it is critical that the version of Hadoop that is out on your cluster matches what your version of HBase needs.

Also, I would suggest you to use the latest stable release of both Hadoop and HBase in order to avoid these problems. 0.20.205 is quite ancient now.

Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

Although, my problem is solved, copying the jar hadoop-core-0.20.205 to lib directory of hbase, It will be great if someone who is experienced in hbase could comment on this one. I'd like to hear an experienced answer